# Using Freemarker DocumentModel with namespaces

Tags: xml, namespaces, freemarker

I am being sent an XML document containing namespace information that I need to process. From all I have read in the documentation I should be able to pass the XML document to the template and use XPath in the template to access the document elements.

I am able to do this successfully on a document that doesn't contain namespaces. But as soon as I introduce namespaces I get an exception.  Here's some sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ns:a xmlns:ns="http://stackoverflow.com/">
  <ns:b>
    <ns:c>Element c</ns:c>
    <ns:d>
      <ns:e>Element e</ns:e>
    </ns:d>
  </ns:b>
</ns:a>
```

And here's my template:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={
  "ns":"http://stackoverflow.com/"}
>

${doc.@@markup}
${doc["/ns:a/ns:b/ns:c"]}
${doc["/ns:a/ns:b/ns:d/ns:e"]}
```

When I apply this template to the XML, I get the following error:

```
Nov 08, 2015 6:31:41 PM freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger error
SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this has evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
==> doc["/ns:a/ns:b/ns:c"]  [in template "freemarker.ftl" at line 6, column 3]

----
Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes. That is, the constructing XML query has found no matches.
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${doc["/ns:a/ns:b/ns:c"]}  [in template "freemarker.ftl" at line 6, column 1]
----
```

I left this out initially, but here is my code that applies the template.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File f = new File("c:/temp/freemarker.xml");
        Configuration c = new Configuration();
        c.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        c.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        c.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("c:/temp"));

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(f);
        Element note = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeModel.simplify(note);
        NodeModel.useJaxenXPathSupport();
        Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        root.put("doc", note);
        Template template = c.getTemplate("freemarker.ftl");

        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        template.process(root, out);

        System.out.println(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As I said, this works fine without namespaces. Unfortunately I can't remove the namespace information is it is possible to have a name conflict that would require the namespace to determine which element is being referenced.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is this possibly a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `xmlns:ns="http://stackoverflow.com/"` from your example XML. If I add that, then it works for me.

Comment: Good catch, @ddekany. I added the namespace int the XML, but I still get the error.  
  
I edited the my initial post to inclue this and also added in the Java code that I use to apply the template.

Comment: Does it work like `${doc["ns:a"]["ns:b"]["ns:c"]}`? Then the probem is with XPath somehow. BTW, I have tested your template and XML on http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/, that's where it has worked.

Comment: Another possibility is that the document builder you are using isn't set to be namespace aware (although I guess that's the default).